# How can I add xml example in Swagger documentation

Tags: xml, api, swagger, documentation

Hello I am creating swagger documentation for an api and I would like to add xml example but I can`t do it.

This is the swagger documentation that I`ve written

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Documentatie API 
  description: Descriere documentatie API metode POST
  version: 1.0.0
host: xxx.ro
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /stareMesaj:
    post:
      summary: Stare mesaj
      description: Descriere stare mesaj
      consumes:

            - application/xml
      produces:

            - application/xml
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
                example: 4
              name:
                type: string
                example: Arthur Dent
```

I was thinking that the proprieties under schema would transform in an example but it says :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XML example cannot be generated; root element name is undefined -->
```

Can you please give me an example ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Your inline schema doesn't have a name, so Swagger UI does not know how to name the root element in XML.

Either add `xml.name` to your schema:

```yaml
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              ...
            xml:           # <-----
              name: user
```

or define a named schema in the `definitions` section and reference it:

```yaml
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/user'

definitions:
  user:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        example: 4
      name:
        type: string
        example: Arthur Dent
```